# How to change popup behaviour for login using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application I use security.xml like this:

```
<security:http pattern="/services/upload" security="none" />
<security:http auto-config='true' create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="digestEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin.html"
        access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/projects/**"
        access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:custom-filter ref="digestFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</security:http>

<bean id="digestFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="digestEntryPoint" />
</bean>

<bean id="digestEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName"
        value="Admin Tab via Digest Authentication" />
    <property name="key" value="acegi" />
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service id="userService">
            <security:user name="xx" password="xx"
                authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

When I click on admin tab on index.html browser pops up its (not controlled by me) form to enter login and password. When I click cancel on this button I get 401 error page. When I enter bad credentials popup resets and doesn't inform me about credentials. What I would like to achieve is to just stay on index.html when user click cancel and show some information if user enters bad credentials. I tried many solutions, but can't get to any solution. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using BasicAuth that means you have to send the credentials with in the request header by encoding Base64. So the browser identifies that and ask the credentials from you. If you want to change this you have to go with the state full scenario. Then you can have custom login page that users can login.

But for the Rest Apis above configuration is correct we don't want to control the login because of it is Basic Auth. For more details take a look at this http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/stateless-spring-security-on-rest-api/